# How can I use my Android 5.1 phone as an external USB Speaker?

Tags: audio

I have a rooted android 5.1 phone and a Acer Apsire 7520 running windows Xp. Can I use the phone as a USB speaker. The laptop doesn't have an audio out or speaker (doesn't work). It does have WiFi and USB connection. But I prefer using USB instead of WiFi.

Answer (score 0):

This android app should actually do this for you seeing that you have WiFi. [Soundwire](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.georgie.SoundWireFree&hl=en&referrer=utm_source%3Dgoogle%26utm_medium%3Dorganic%26utm_term%3Duse%20android%20as%20wireless%20pc%20headset&pcampaignid=APPU_fA3EVKPnEPf8sAS-uYKQCA) Install the windows program downloadable from their website run it and set what audio you want to output to your phone you'll be assigned a server address. Input this into your app on your phone and your golden.

Comment: I like your idea, but I have tried it and found it doesn't run parallel to the incoming sound. In other words sort of incompatible.