# Stream audio from external hardware to android phone via USB

Tags: usb, usb-connection-mode, usb-on-the-go, usb-drivers, usb-host-mode

What I have done till now

- I am able to connect an external hardware to my android device via USB.
- After detection of external hardware, I am establishing an USB connection.
- After connection I am able to read/write data through app.

**Now what I need is to stream FM modulated audio to android device speaker and audio port.**

Does android automatically does it for us, as we do stream music over BT headset using A2DP profile or we need to create some sort of player and enable some functions of device ?

After going through multiple docs and android developer site itself, I come upto AOA2 protocol that allows android device to stream audio to its attached accessories via USB.

As per the docs an Android device can't act as USB speakers.

Is there any alternative way we can make an Android device as USB speakers for any external Hardware.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Similar thing asked for here: [How can I use my Android 5.1 phone as an external USB Speaker?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/150541/16575) And maybe here: [How to stream audio from PC to android device through USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/122879/16575) Oh, and [Is there a way to stream all audio from PC to Android via USB?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/10350/16575) // [Can I use my PC as an audio device for my Android phone?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/39884/16575)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the revert. Actually in my scenario I need to play audio of FM( Radio ) over the android phone through my  app.  This FM is an external hardware that will be plugged in to USB of device. By time I am able  to create a connection with that USB device and also I am able to read and write data. Not able to get, how  that audio will be transferred via USB to android phone. Really stuck in this. Would really appreciate any help over this. :)